# Is there a word for a subset of English specifically designed to be easily understood by non-native speakers?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, present-tense, non-native-english

Looking at examples like Basic English or Simple English, I see phrases like "controlled language" or "controlled vocabulary". Is there a simpler word?

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/varieties-and-types-of-english) lists classmates of 'Basic English' (which, I believe, has a specific definition as a compound noun). There don't seem to be any synonyms.

Comment: *English for beginners*  is an expression often used in basic English texts for foreign learners. https://www.google.it/search?biw=1865&bih=928&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=-veXWs7LE4n-UOzDpJAD&q=english+for+beginners+&oq=english+for+beginners+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1l8j0i30i19k1l2.17284.17822.0.18212.5.5.0.0.0.0.141.577.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.572...0i8i30i19k1.0.j5blOocIWRU

Comment: Since 'control' is included in the Basic English word list, I'd guess there isn't a simpler version.

Comment: There are s number of controlled languages like Simplified English, developed by AECMA (Association Europeene des
Constructeurs de Materiel Aerospatial), and mandated by the Air
Transport Association as the world-wide standard for commercial aircraft maintenance
manuals.  See [Chap 7, part 5 here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/pdf-files/7-8-buch.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

> [Basic English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English)

or

> [World English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_English),

with their different nuances, are the simplest terms that capture exactly what you are asking about.

Basic English is a selection, a simple subset of English for easy learning, intended to allow good communication early in the learning process.

World English is an attempt to label the common subset of English as spoken around the world by educated non-native speakers.

But there is no *single* word that captures such a subset. It seems almost impossible to have one given that what you are asking for is a qualification of English.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever listen to English-speaking expats abroad, the ones that are good communicators intentionally use very simple words with often hilariously simplified grammar. That's

> **pidgin**
>
> : a simplified speech used for communication between people with different languages

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pidgin

Specifically, it's pidgin English.

When people grow up speaking pidgin, it becomes a

> **creole**

Comment: Explain the downvotes. Having re-read the question, I stand by my answer.